# MVC method call working in Fiddler, but not in browser

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am able to get a result back from a method call in Fiddler using the below syntax:

```
http://localhost:1196/Home/GetSpecificFuelTicketAsync/6460194
```

Note that as going through Fiddler, my controller breakpoints are hit and I can see where it returns a value coming out of the method.

However, I am not able to get a result back when running from my browser. When it tries to execute the ajax method, the "success" function does not fire and skips to the "error" function where it says it can't find the record.

**What am I doing wrong with my ajax call?** There is something I am definitely doing wrong in my ajax call. I have verified during debugging, that the variable "ticketNbr" actually contains a value.

Here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                            url: "Home/GetSpecificFuelTicketAsync",
                            data: "{id:" + ticketNbr + "}",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                DisplayReceipt(data);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("No record found for ticket " + ticketNbr);
                            }
                        });
```

Here is my Route.config file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Here is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetSpecificFuelTicketAsync(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                string imageID = await db.GetSpecificFuelTicketAsync(id);

                return Json(imageID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strRemedyTktResponse = IssueRemedyTicket("Class: FuelTktController" + CrLf + "Method: GetSpecificFuelTicket" + CrLf + "Error: " + ex.Message + CrLf + "InnerException: " + ex.InnerException + CrLf + "Source: " + ex.Source + CrLf + "StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
                LogMessage.WriteEventLog("Class: FuelTktController" + CrLf + "Method: GetSpecificFuelTicket" + CrLf + "Error: " + ex.Message + CrLf + "InnerException: " + ex.InnerException + CrLf + "Source: " + ex.Source + CrLf + "StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace, "FuelTktController", 1, strRemedyTktResponse);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `url: "Home/GetSpecificFuelTicketAsync/" + ticketNbr`

Comment: what is the error? have you looked at the network tab of your browser's developer tools (chrome dev tools or firebug)?

Comment: First, I suggest modifying your error callback to include the parameters that will give you more information about the error, including the status code, which will help debugging. The signature of that method is `function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`. You can console.log each parameter to see the values.

Comment: Have you tried stepping in to your Action method? Does it hit that or does it fail first?

Comment: Try `data: JSON.stringify({ id: ticketNbr })` and adding `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: Thanks everyone... I forgot to add the contentType and also did not have my parameter formatted correctly. Curtis, I took your advice and will apply the error parms inside the error handler for further debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might just be the way you are defining your ajax call.. try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetSpecificFuelTicketAsync")',
    data: "{'id': '" + ticketNbr + "'}",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        DisplayReceipt(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("No record found for ticket " + ticketNbr);
    }
});
```

Comment: I would suggest taking it a step further and using `JSON.stringify({ id: ticketNbr })`. There are too many edge cases to build json strings via concatenation.

Comment: it's really picky about the quotes around the json variables.. i found that was the main issue

Answer (score 1):

Change this line  -

```
data: "{id:" + ticketNbr + "}",
```

to this -

```
data: "id=" + ticketNbr,
```

or this -

```
data : {id: ticketNbr} //loose the quotations.
```

and try again.

With this controller method the next one is even better option -

```
$.ajax({
                            url: "Home/GetSpecificFuelTicketAsync/" + ticketNbr,
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                DisplayReceipt(data);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("No record found for ticket " + ticketNbr);
                            }
                        });
```